# OpenCV copyTo() mask error

Tags: c++, opencv, mask

I'm trying to paste a smaller image into a larger image, using masks in OpenCV 2.4 via C++. 
Without a mask, I copy the small image to the larger image with the following code:

```
smallImage.copyTo(largeImage(cv::Rect(pt, smallImage.size()));
```

where `pt` has the type of `cv::Point2f`. It works perfectly. However, if I apply a mask:

```
smallImage.copyTo(largeImage(cv::Rect(pt, smallImage.size()), mask);
```

I get an error from `Mat::create` (see [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=copyto#void%20Mat%3a%3acopyTo%28OutputArray%20m,%20InputArray%20mask%29%20const)):

```
CV_Assert(!fixedType() || (CV_MAT_CN(type) ==
    m.channels() && ((1 << CV_MAT_TYPE(flags)) & fixedDepthMask) != 0));
```

If I remove the `cv::Rect` from my code, simplifying it to:

```
smallImage.copyTo(largeImage, mask);
```

it works, albeit it doesn't copy to the correct location. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works without any error.

```
    Mat large_img = imread("C:\\Koala.jpg");
    Mat small_img;
    resize(large_img,small_img,Size(100,100),1);
    small_img.copyTo(large_img (Rect(100,100,100,100)));
    imshow("Rsult",large_img);
    waitKey(0);
```

The small image is re-sized version of large image and it is copied in b/w (100,100) location to (200,200) in the large image. You can adopt these lines according to your requirement.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much for your response!  However, my issue is with using masks.  I would like to only copy certain pixels (as defined by the mask) to the "largeImage" from the "smallImage."  How would I go about doing that?  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I was able to solve my issue by first placing the "small image" in a larger image, and then applying a mask.  Thanks for all the ideas and help!

Answer (score 0):

To paste a image scaledImage to resultMat:

```
 scaledImage.copyTo(resultMat);
```

But i don't think you can select a roi in Java to copy at a particular region.